# How are statistics determined for an awakened animal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, animals

## Do published [awakened](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm) creatures exist?

Is there a stat block in any official text—including *Dragon* and *Dungeon* magazines—for a creature that's been the target of the 5th-level Drd spell [*awaken*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm) [trans] (*PH* 202)?

## What are the rules for an [awakened](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm) creature's extra Hit Dice?

For example, a Drd9 casts the spell [*awaken*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/awaken.htm), targeting a [rat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/rat.htm) so that the now "awakened [rat] gets 3d6 Intelligence, +1d3 Charisma, and +2 HD. Its type becomes magical beast (augmented animal)." The DM rolls Int 11 and +2 Cha, making the rat's ability scores Str 2, Dex 15, Con 10, Int 11, Wis 12, and Cha 4. Conveniently, the rat names himself [Reepicheep](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0037150/).

[image: You'll *Reep* what you sow! Sigh. I'm also betting his Charisma should be higher.]

Reepicheep starts with HD ¼d8 and from the spell *awaken* gains 2 Hit Dice. But are these new 2 Hit Dice animal Hit Dice or magical beast Hit Dice? And does Reepicheep's starting Hit Die *stay* an animal Hit Die or does it *become* a magical beast Hit Die?

Applying as best I can the rules for [Increasing Hit Dice](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm#increasingHitDice), the differences are pronounced.

- With HD 2¼d8 (animal), Reepicheep has hp 10, base attack bonus +2, and base saving throws (without ability score adjustments) of Fort +3, Ref +3, and Will +1.
- With HD 2¼d10 (magical beast), Reepicheep has hp 12, base attack bonus +3, and base saving throws of Fort +3, Ref +3, and Will +1.
- With HD ¼d8 (animal) +2d10 (magical beast), Reepicheep has hp 12, base attack bonus +2, and base saving throws of Fort +5, Ref +5, Will +0. *Note:* Here I've computed Reepicheep's statistics as if he'd, in essence, multiclassed into magical beast.

Is there a correct way to determine an awakened creature's statistics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for the first part of your question, I know of none, but I know very little outside the rules.

As for the second question,

## Variant 1 is correct

An awakened animal retains all Animal features, features being a game term that encompasses HD, BAB and Saves.

The spell description states

> An awakened animal['s] type becomes **magical beast (augmented animal)**.

Looking at [Augmented](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#augmentedSubtype), we get

> A creature with the augmented subtype usually has the traits of its current type, but the features of its original type.

Since *awaken* does not specify differently, an awakened animal is a "usual" Magical Beast (Augmented Animal), meaning it has the Features of an [Animal](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#animalType) paired with the traits of a [Magical Beast](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#magicalBeastType).

> **Features**
>   An animal has the following features (unless otherwise noted in a creature’s entry).
>
> - 8-sided Hit Dice.
> - Base attack bonus equal to ¾ total Hit Dice (as cleric).
> - Good Fortitude and Reflex saves (certain animals have different good saves, for instance dire animals have good Fortitude, Reflex, and Will saves).
> - Skill points equal to (2 + Int modifier, minimum 1) per Hit Die, with quadruple skill points for the first Hit Die.
>
> **Traits**
>   A magical beast possesses the following traits (unless otherwise noted in a creature’s entry).
>
> - Darkvision out to 60 feet and low-light vision.
> - Proficient with its natural weapons only.
> - Proficient with no armor.
> - Magical beasts eat, sleep, and breathe.

---

Note that by RAW, the replacement of the Animal traits with that of a Magical Beast means that animal loses proficiency with all armor, even if it was war-trained prior to its awakening.